# How does drawLine Work?

Tags: java, line, draw, graphics2d, stroke

In order to solve a scaling problem, I have the following question:
`graphics.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);` draws a line between 2 points.
Does it draw this Lines "on Top" of those points or is it drawn below them?
See my Image for clarification:
[image: Example]
The upper example shows how an Oval is drawn with `graphics.fillOval(x,y,w,h);` where the black point is the x and y coordinate and the red circle is the actual oval...
Is it the same using `graphics.drawLine()` when using a `new BasicStroke(3.5f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND)` like in the lower example?
Or is the line actually drawn centered to the coordinates?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea. But why don't you just test it and see?

Comment: @JBNizet how could I test this?

Comment: To better understand the problem, you'll need to draw a grid to represent pixels, and then fill them in to show how the geometric primitives are rendered.

Comment: Draw a 1x1 rectangle to mark the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drawLine(), the beginning of the arc portion will be at x location, so your picture is wrong. The rounded cap will protrude to the left of the left dot, and to the right of the right dot.